# Date range in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a requirement where the data needs to be retreived starting from a particluar month but for a years period only. Example would be all data dated from 1st August 2019 till a year after, which would be 1st August 2020. The month value could vary, so in this example it is August but it could be May or September as well.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Reports
WHERE
  Fromdate BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND DATE_ADD('2019-08-01', INTERVAL 365 DAY)
ORDER BY dateFrom ASC;
```

Here *between* will only pick up data for 2019 and 365 days after but 2019 is baked in. How should i put the selection criteria in the between clause so that it is dynamic? I am thinking along the lines of below where i would declare a variable for the month but i am not sure how to specify the 365 days from that month.

```
set @monthSelected = 8; -- August

SELECT 
    *
FROM
   Reports
WHERE
   month(Fromdate) = @monthSelected
   and Fromdate BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND DATE_ADD('2019-08-01', INTERVAL 365 DAY)
ORDER BY dateFrom ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i came up with,

```
set @curYear = 2019 ;-- concat("'",Year(now()));
set @monthSelected = '10';

set @dateF = concat(@curYear,'-',@monthSelected,'-01',"'") ;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Reports
WHERE
  Fromdate BETWEEN @dateF AND DATE_ADD(@dateF , INTERVAL 365 DAY);
```

A bit crude and a bit on the slow slide but it seems to be working. Am open to hear other suggestions.